# Cannot remote into raspberry pi via hostname

Tags: ssh, raspberry-pi, remote-access, putty

Let me start by saying that I have no experience with Linux and this is my first attempt at getting into the IoT with a raspberry pi3. My question is why can I connect via ssh to my pi when I use the ip address but not the hostname?

After getting everything set up at home, I tried to remote in via PuTTY from my laptop. (The laptop is less than 6 months old and if I need to provide the specs on it, I can. It is running windows 10 if that matters). It worked when I entered the ip address of the pi, but when I tried again with the host name (which is clearly defined in the raspberry pi configuration) it said host does not exist. I used hostname.local and still failed.

Today, I brought the whole setup to work to try a few more scenarios. From my work desktop, which is running windows 7 and not wireless, I could remote in via hostname.local. I then tried again on a different laptop running windows 7 and it worked too. Next attempt was on another new (less than 3 months old) laptop running windows 10 and it failed to remote in via the hostname.

This would tell me that there is nothing wrong with my home network or the network at work, and it also makes me think that this has nothing to do with the pi, since other computers can resolve the hostname to the ip address and successfully login. What the hell am I doing wrong or missing?

I spent 2 nights googling and browsing forums trying to find an answer for this but cant, so instead of bashing this post, please poke me for more information you think might be helpful for a solution.

**EDIT** I gave my computer and PI to my cousin to fix. He installed Samba, though I don't know what it does differently. After doing more research, it sounds like the problem I was having was a DNS issue. I don't know how it was resolved by downloading samba on the pi, but I can now connect via the hostname.

Comment: Show me `nslookup hostname` on window 10 host.

Comment: http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/116622/82046

Answer (score 0):

So if I understand correctly it would appear that there is some particular settings on that laptop preventing you from using SSH if that is the only thing you are changing? I think this is likely to be something to do with the security settings on the laptop but Windows isn't my thing sorry.